# Firebase Auth: This app is not authorized to use Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My app/build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0"
```

And in DEBUG mode I sucess auth. by Firebase Auth.

1. Input phone number
2. Get sms
3. Success confirm by sms

OK. It's work fine.

But when I want to do this in release mode I get the next error:

[image: Error_Firebase_auth]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to project settings

[image]

and at the bottom click

[image]

See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth for how to create the SHA1

Comment: that's for release APK?

Comment: Sorry, don't remember. I haven't worked with Firebase since more than a year.

Comment: NOTE! There is a limit of about 11 sha1's on firebase

Answer (score 0):

Add SHA1 from google play console . If you public app you must get SHA1 from your google play console and add it in firebase setting.
It worked for me when i publiced my app has google sign in feature firebase.
I know it too late for answer but hope it help for someone else in present.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a SHA1 and SHA-256 into your firebase fingerprint

Step1: Run this command into your project terminal
"cd .\android" and then
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\Users\User_name.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
You will get a SHA keys
Step 2: Copy those keys and add them inside the firebase fingerprint inside Project settings->users